# how to create intervals without pausing entire app ( android studio )

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wait, sleep

how do i create intervals in a loop without pausing the entire app? Whenever I call Thread.sleep or Timunit.sleep it pauses the entire application. I'm currently trying to do something with a while loop and want one second intervals each time.

(edit - It's a pretty simple question so I don't think I need to put in any of my code, but if you need any of it just ask )

Comment: You don't.  There's almost never a reason to do that, and ABSOLUTELY NEVER a reason to do it on the main thread.  If you think you need to do it, you're not using event driven programming correctly.  You should specify what you're trying to do so someone can tell you the right way to do it.

Comment: i'm just trying to create a loop with one second intervals so I can output something every second.

Comment: Use a handler and post a delayed message to it to run in one second. Sleep on the main thread is never correct.

Comment: handler didn't work but I did fix my problem by simply creating a new thread. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
  public static ScheduledExecutorService sScheduledExecutor;
  sScheduledExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  sScheduledExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
           // Do something you want
       }
   }, 0, 1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```